# Strange working php code regarding protected visibility

Tags: php, visibility

```
class Fruit {
    protected $blend;

    public function WillItBlend() {
        return $this->blend;
    }
    public static function MakeFruit() {
        $objF = new Fruit();
        $objF->blend = true;
        return $objF;
    }
}

$fruit = Fruit::MakeFruit();
echo $fruit->WillItBlend();
```

Why is this line working

```
$objF->blend = true;
```

instead of throwing a Fatal error ?

Comment: +1 for making me want a smoothie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visibility modifiers work at the class level, not at the object level.  This also means that objects of the same class can access each other's private bits.

An example at the PHP interactive prompt:

```
php > class Foo {
        private $bar;
        public function __construct() { $this->bar = rand(1, 100); } 
        public function baz($another_foo) { echo $another_foo->bar, '-', $this->bar; }
    }
php > $a = new Foo();
php > $b = new Foo();
php > $a->baz($b);
86-70
```

Answer (score 1):

`$objF` is instance of class `Fruit`.

`$objF->blend` is being used in class itself. `Protected` properties can be used in class itself.

You will get Fatal Error if you use it outside the class as `$fruit->blend;`

So it is allowed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

because you're accessing it from inside the class, if you would call from outside the class

```
$fruit = Fruit::MakeFruit();
echo $fruit->WillItBlend();
echo $fruit->blend;
```

it would throw a fatal error.